# Using Cortana for dictation of documents

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, cortana

I'm currently doing research about Cortana as I'm interested in doing some development of custom skills for it. Currently I'm using Cortana to invoke Windows Speech Recognition where I can then use WSR as a means to dictate text into Word. I'm experimenting with this as a possibility to be used for recording and generating a transcript in real time for meetings.

Now this is quite a hassle as I've found and I'm curious to know if there is something that I can do to integrate a bot within Cortana for the same purpose. I've looked up and done some reading about Azure Bot Framework, Cognitive Services, LUIS, etc.

Is it possible to develop such a solution using the above mentioned services ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can feed the streams to the [Speech to Text API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/), then chunk the audio according to the returned `Offset` and `Duration` of each phrase, then send those chunks to the [Speaker Recognition API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/?v=18.05) to identify the speaker by name so you'd have a name for each chunk to put with it's transcribed phrase and create a dialog out of

Since you're considering it mainly for meetings, the solution you've mentioned was announced a while ago as a feature of Microsoft Teams, and it is going to be publicly available in the near feature, you can also watch a demo that was presented at Build 2018 from [here](https://youtu.be/ddb3ZgAp9TA)

Comment: Hey Ali,

That demo was awesome. I didn't see the follow up about the integration so thank you for that. It looks very promising tbh.

About my OC about the bot. I've currently set up bot with the Bot Services using the Language Understanding template. I'm guessing what I need to do now is write intents that will allow my bot to understand that I want it to make a transcript and then use the Bing Speech API for example to have it type down text from the audio stream I'm providing using a microphone ? 

Does that sound like the right interpretation on my part ?

Regards

Comment: Yes it is, please let me know if you need further help in the implementation.